# Проблемма с синтаксисом String.IndexOf

Tags: c#

Вот код:

```
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
if (answer.IndexOf("окей")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("ну окей, так окей");
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы код находил слово окей в переменной answer, которую вводит пользователь в консоль. Поправьте пожалуйста меня. Что я написал тут не так?

Comment: `if (answer.IndexOf("окей") != -1)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо большое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает *индекс с отсчетом от нуля первого вхождения значения указанной строки в данном экземпляре.* Вам нужно проверить, равен ли результат значению большему чем -1.

Проще воспользоваться [**`String.Contains`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Возвращает значение, указывающее, содержит ли указанная строка значение подстроки переданной в качестве параметра.

[Демо-код на C#](https://ideone.com/GbBP6U):

```
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
if (answer.Contains("окей")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("ну окей, так окей");
}
```

Comment: а если будет введен ответ "не окей"?

Comment: @tCode: А что такого? Пользователь ввёл "не окей", строка содержит "окей", значит, надо вывести "ну окей, так окей" :) Это ж машина, что ей скажешь, то и сделает.

Comment: да это я так... скучно просто)

Comment: Пожалуйста: [*-Гиви, ты коньяк пить будешь ?
-А почему бы и нет ?
-Ну нет - так нет !*](http://www.anekdot.ru/id/-1051700047/)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это мне подходит даже больше, чем IndexOf.